# Facebook Graph JS api Cover does not return on Localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Issue just found out.

When your app is running on http://localhost/something and if you try to get the cover photo of the current logged in user, it will not work [ I'm not getting the expected results, The commented response is what I get [mentioned above], Not the response object which contains the cover: {} ].

```
FB.api('me?fields=cover', function(r) { console.log(r)})
// r => {id: somerandomnumber}
```

Any work throughs for this issue when I'm developing the app ?

**EDIT**
After much work and @Lix help found out that I need `user_photos` permission to get the cover photo of the logged in user through graph api.

But the weirdest thing is that on this http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth-javascript/index.php website even though I do not have to give permission to `user_photos` I still can get my (  currently logged in ) cover photo

Is this a Graph api versioning issue ?

Comment: Please define `"will not work"` - are you seeing any errors? What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: definition of not work = I'm not getting the expected results, The commented response is what I get [mentioned above], Not the response object which contains the ``cover: {}``

Comment: Are you sure that this `id` value is not the `id` of the actual cover photo? Do you get different results when removing the cover field from the request?

Comment: Nope, because I copy paste the same code on graph api explorer and it returns my cover photo object, but the same code does not return the cover photo object on http://localhost

Comment: Do you agree with me on this @Lix >?

Comment: I can't see your code or the results and I don't have access to your local environment so I have no way of validating what you are saying. Try swap between the access tokens you have locally and have generated from the API explorer - use the API Explorer token locally and use your local token with the API Explorer. See if there is any difference when using the alternative tokens...

Comment: Wow, good thinking! I just copied the temp access token from Graph explorer and had the same FB.api funtcion run with the access_token and then I received the cover photo object.  So now we have established it is an issue with access_tokens

Comment: Yep, I copied the locally generated access_token to Graph api explorer and I did not get the cover photo object on my response :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to request the `photos` permission to get access to the user's cover photo. Were you requesting this permission on your local implementation?

Comment: No, I just do not want anything other than the public_profile

Comment: If you only want the `public_profile` information then why then are you requesting the cover photo?

Comment: I do not think it is with permission issue, If it is permission issue api would have thrown an error, I tested my above mentioned code here http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth-javascript/index.php and that gives me the cover photo of the logged in user. Which is me, So this is defanitly http://localhost issue,

Comment: Let me explain, I try to replicate the facebook layout, Facebook profile picture and the background ( cover photo ) it is not about why I guess, It is about how we do it... Lets solve this mystery

Comment: Do the two access tokens you are using have the same permissions?

Comment: Yeah, For example I just allow my ``public_profile`` permissions here http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth-javascript/index.php And on the console I still can get the cover photo object using the ``FB.api...``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84291/discussion-between-sahan-and-lix).

Comment: Sorry friend, I'm currently at work and don't have time to jump into chat.

Comment: Na, No worries, Thanks so much all the help you have done so far :) Appreciate it

Comment: No problem! Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a Graph api versioning issue ?

Yes, it is.

Using versions up to and including v2.3 would give you access to the user’s cover photo with `public_profile` permission alone, but now Facebook has changed the possibilities for users to restrict the visibility of their cover photos more, they will not necessarily be “public” any more.

You can easily test this in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). Give your app only `public_profile` permission – then the request for `/me?fields=cover` will return the cover field if you choose API version 2.3 or lower from the dropdown, but not any more with 2.4. If you use that, you will have to grant `user_photos` permission as well to see the content of the field.